# High-dimensional uniform distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $\mathcal X$ be either a subset of $\mathbb R$ equipped with Lebesgue measure or a countable set with counting measure.
The Gibbs' principle in statistical physics asserts that if $(X_1 , \dots, X_n) \in \mathcal X^n$ is distributed uniformly on
$$
\left\{  (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathcal X^n: \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_a(x_i) \in [m_a, m_a+\delta], \quad a=1,\dots,k \right\}
$$
where $m_1,\dots, m_k$ are fixed,
then as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and then $\delta \rightarrow 0$ , $X_1, \dots, X_n $ are *asymptotically i.i.d.* with the marginal law
$$
P_X(x) \propto e^{\sum_{a=1}^k \lambda_a m_a(x)} \tag{1}
$$
where $(\lambda_a)$ are such that
$$
\mathbb E[f_a(X)] = m_a \tag{2}
$$
Note that $P_X$ is also the probability law with maximum entropy subjected to the constraints (2).

This is not a mathematical theorem, it works for a lot of cases in physics and there are cases where it fails. For the physicists, *asymptotically i.i.d.* means that they can do the calculations with the easy i.i.d. distribution instead of the uniform distribution and get the same result.

One interesting example (https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4043) in which this prniciple fails is when $\mathcal X = (0, \infty)$, with $k=2$,$f_1(x) = x$, $f_2(x) = x^2$, $m_1=1, m_2 > 2$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for any fixed $k$, $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ converges in law to $(Z_1, \dots, Z_k)$, where $Z_i \stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim} \text{Exp}(1)$.

Now take $\mathcal X = \mathbb R$, $k=2, f_1(x) = x^2, f_2(x)=x^3$, then Gibbs' principle fails since there is no real-valued random variable with density $P_X(x) \propto e^{ax^2+bx^3}$. Which result can be obtained in this case? Does the uniform law behave like a more simple law as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: How do you define this uniform distribution? How do you do the quartic case? Why is it significantly different from the cubic one?

Comment: It's the same thing as uniform distribution on a compact manifold. The result for quartic case is an easy consequence of the equivalence between canonical and micro-canonical ensemble in statistical physics, although this equivalence does not hold for all kind of energy function, and there is no general math theorem about it. If we blindly apply this physical heuristic, we get the marginal $P(x) \propto e^{ax^3+bx^2}$ which is not well defined on $\mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Also, do you mind sharing how this problem arises?

Comment: A uniform distribution on a compact manifold makes sense once a Riemannian metric has been defined on it. I presume that the metric here is the one inherited from euclidean space — is that right?

Comment: @DanielAsimov Yes. My background is physics and my way to visualize the uniform distribution on a compact manifold in $ \mathbb R^n$ is 1) choosing a box that contains the manifold 2) choose uniformly randomly a very large number of points inside this box 3) only keep the points that are very close to the manifold

Comment: @IosifPinelis This question is somewhat related to the principle of maximum entropy https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Principle_of_maximum_entropy. The cubic constraint corresponds to the following case https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#/Maximizer_for_specified_mean,_variance_and_skew

Comment: Another important thing I haven't mentioned is that in the quadratic and quartic case, the physical heuristic predicts that $X_i$ are asymptotically i.i.d, which means the joint distribution $(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ converges in law to $P_{X_1}^{\otimes k}$ for any finite $k$. So understand the marginal is the key to understand this high-dimensional uniform distribution.

Comment: Is $m$ fixed? I think the answer will depend significantly on whether $m$ is $0$ or not. Do you want to consider both cases?

Comment: Yes $m$ is fixed.

Comment: I guess the answer should be that the distribution is obtained by maximizing entropy over random variables satisfying $\mathbb E(X^2)=1$ and $\mathbb E(X^3)=m$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Yes but such random variable does not exist.

Comment: @Pluviophile : How to show that your posted question is equivalent to the problem of maximizing entropy over random variables $X$ with $EX^2=1$ and $EX^3=m$ (as you seem to assert)? Is it something easy, or do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: this is just intuition on my part.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I've updated the question.

Comment: By analogy with Sourav's result, it would be natural to conjecture that you're again asymptotically i.i.d. normal, but that one of the $x_i$'s will typically be about $(mn)^{1/3}$.

Comment: @Pluviophile : Thank you for this additional information. However, I still don't see a connection to maximizing entropy. Can you say more on that -- preferably in mathematical terms (as I know next to nothing in statistical physics)?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I added a new line in the question under the equation (2).

Comment: @MartinHairer Thank you for your comment. I found out that paper while trying to add more information to the question. I'll take a deeper look at it.

Comment: @Pluviophile : Oh, that was clear to me. But is that more than a mere coincidence?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I guess it has something to do with the fact that the uniform distribution is the least informative given the constraints $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i f_a(x_i)=m_a$, while the maximum entropy law is the least informative given the constraints $\mathbb E[f_a(X)]=m_a$.

Comment: @Pluviophile : Alas, I still don't see a connection. On the one hand, we are talking about the entropy of distributions on a multidimensional compact Riemann manifold -- without restrictions on the distributions, so that the uniform one is the maximizer. On the other hand, about the entropy of distributions on the entire real line -- with affine restrictions on the distributions, and then a maximizer (or any distribution) cannot possibly be uniform.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Perhaps, this has something to do with the intuition that the uniform distribution on the compact Riemann manifold is approximately a product measure in some sense (?).

Comment: @IosifPinelis I guess the product measure in this case is the result of this particular type of constraints.